# Saving reservations using available 2 halls

Tags: php, codeigniter

Below is the function for saving some reservation details to the database. `get_hall()` query returns 2 halls(haal1 and hall2). bus when going to the database only hall1 is inserting. I want to insert hall1 next reservation hall2. How to improve below code.

```
function save_reserve_detail($date,$time,$flag){
    $halls = $this->halls_model->get_hall();
       foreach ($halls AS $each) {
           $hall = $each['hall_id'];
           break;
       }
    $reference_no = date("YmdHis");
       if ($flag == 1) {
           $hall_id = $hall;
           $type = 1;  
           $date = $date;
       } else if ($flag == 2) {
           $hall_id = $hall;
           $type = 0;
           $date = $date;
       }
    $data = array(
        'reference_no' => $reference_no,
        'date' => $date,
        'type' => $type,
        'hall' => $hall
    );
    $result = $this->db->insert('reserving_details', $data);
    if ($result) {
         return $reference_no;
    } else {
         return 0;
    }
```

}

Comment: what is `$flag` here? its not defined?

Comment: @Chetan Ameta my mistake, I added $flag check now.

Comment: why you used break inside foreach? it will breaks the loop after one execution. so it returns single value

Comment: when I remove break only hall2 goes to the database. how to fix this @VigneswaranS

Comment: now print_r($hall) and say the result whether it is an array or not ? and also edit your question by adding  insert() ;code

Comment: db->insert('reserve_details', $data); can you add the code for insert function

Comment: @VigneswaranS when removed `break;` then `print_r($hall);` returns this `hall1hall2`

Comment: have your problem solved now ? check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Remove the break from foreach . now the $hall contains an array of 2 values. now use a for loop to insert the value into the table.

```
<?php
  function save_reserve_detail($date,$time,$flag){
        $halls = $this->halls_model->get_hall();
           foreach ($halls AS $each) {
               $hall = $each['hall_id'];
              // break;
           }
        $reference_no = date("YmdHis");
           if ($flag == 1) {
               $hall_id = $hall;
               $type = 1;  
               $date = $date;
           } else if ($flag == 2) {
               $hall_id = $hall;
               $type = 0;
               $date = $date;
           }
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($hall);$i++){
     $data = array(
            'reference_no' => $reference_no,
            'date' => $date,
            'type' => $type,
            'hall' => $hall[$i]
        );
        $result = $this->db->insert('reserving_details', $data);
        if ($result) {
             return $reference_no;
        } else {
             return 0;
        }

}

    }

?>
```

Even you can alter your insert('reserving_details', $data); code which can handle array insertion.

Comment: not working only `hall2`goes to the db @VigneswaranS

Comment: @saku: not possible. if print_r($hall); gives hall1, hall2 then this for loop should work. can you say it again what print_r($hall); gives?

Comment: to check the functionalities assign  'hall' => $hall[$i] to  'hall' => $hall[0] and try now hall1 one should get saved